# My laptop sometimes slow down and the response time increases until i log out

Tags: freeze, bug-reporting

I have acer f5-573g laptop (CPU: i7 7700U , RAM: 16g ddr4). I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver). sometimes everything slow down like animations, keyboard, running applications and etc. When i log out and log in again then problem solves and everything runs smooth!

**My applications list:**

- Ubuntu applications
- vsCode
- some packages like g++, FLTK, glfw and etc.

**What i did?**

- installed Ubuntu on SSD and once again on HDD
- installed Nvidia drivers (4 different versions)
- update and upgrade Ubuntu (all applications, kernel and everything else)
- installed *top* package and checked CPU, RAM and applications but everything is normal
- installed OpenGL and enabled/disabled V-Sync and other parameters
- removed Gnome and installed KDE
- checked internet connection, proxy, mouse, keyboard, bios settings and lots of other things i thought it might be effective

Unfortunately, my problem is not solved yet. Doesn't anyone think of a solution?

Comment: Sounds like thermal throttling. What thermal management are you using? tlp, thermald? Monitor things with this turbostat command: `sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 15`. If you do not have thermal management then as a test try to limit the CPU frequency manually. By default you should be using the intel-pstate CPU frequency driver, do: `echo 70 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`.